# How to build boost library on Linux machine and using in QNX 7.1

Tags: boost, conan, qnx

I'm trying to build boost library on Linux machine and it can use on QNX7.1.
I used conan package to build boost. The build error log is shown as below:

```
Cross-build from 'Linux:x86_64' to 'Neutrino:x86_64'
Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
b2/4.9.3: Already installed!
bzip2/1.0.8: Already installed!
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: WARN: Build folder is dirty, removing
checking for gcc... qcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/home/user/.conan/data/libbacktrace/cci.20210118/_/_/build/487843ee4e66cda082d78c49de1887320a778ff1/build-debug':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: 
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: ERROR: Package '487843ee4e66cda082d78c49de1887320a778ff1' build failed
libbacktrace/cci.20210118: WARN: Build folder /home/user/.conan/data/libbacktrace/cci.20210118/_/_/build
        '
```

I'm using below config:

```
include(default)
[settings]
os=Neutrino
os.version=7.1
arch=x86_64

compiler=qcc
compiler.libcxx=cxx
compiler.version=8.3

os_build=Linux
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Debug
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]
CC=qcc
CXX=q++
CONAN_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/qnx.cmake
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$QNX_HOST/usr/bin/q++
CMAKE_C_COMPILER=$QNX_HOST/usr/bin/qcc
CXX=$QNX_HOST/usr/bin/q++
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[$QNX_HOST/usr/lib]
MAKEFLAGS=-I$QNX_TARGET/usr/include
```

Comment: It looks to me like the problem is with compiling libbacktrace, one of the dependencies for boost's conan package.  You may be running in to this bug in conan: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/8290  
You might be able to work around this by disabling "with_stacktrace_backtrace" in the boost conan package building instructions.

Comment: @WillMiles, Thank you for your support
From my side, I have workaround by adding a flag in conanfile.py in  libbacktrace library
    def generate(self):
        env = VirtualBuildEnv(self)
        env.generate()

        tc = AutotoolsToolchain(self)
        tc.configure_args.extend([
            f"--host={self.settings.arch}"
        ])
With workaround above i can pass the issue above.

But reached new issue with boost

Comment: - has_icu builds           : no [2]
    - zlib                     : yes [3]
    - bzip2                    : yes [3]
    - iconv (libc)             : no [2]
- Boost.Locale failed to find iconv (libc) library to be built.

Comment: That's the opposite problem: the boost conan package does not list `libiconv` as a dependency, but it should.   You can fix this by either porting `libiconv` or disabling `Boost.Locale`.

Comment: @WillMiles In my project I need Boost.Locale. that is why i try to build with porting libiconv
by set ''' "i18n_backend_iconv": "libiconv"''. If i try by this way i got another issue
'''libs/locale/src/posix/numeric.cpp:26:10: fatal error: monetary.h: No such file or directory'''

Comment: From what I can tell, monetary.h is not a required POSIX header and is not supplied by QNX.   Either your libiconv cross-build is incorrectly configured with information from the build host; or you'll have to port libiconv to QNX by shimming or removing whatever feature depends on it.